# Transaction is still open after cancelling query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, transactions

In sql server 2008, I am using a pattern like this:

```
begin transaction

begin try

/* do something */

end try

begin catch

if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
rollback

 DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int                              
  SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),                              
         @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()                              

  RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity,1)     

end catch

if @@TRANCOUNT > 0
commit transaction
```

when I hit "Cancel Executing Query" button on Sql Server Management Studio it cancels the query and leaves the transaction open.

Is this the intended behavior? Or is there a mistake in my pattern. Shouldn't it rollback the transaction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IMHO, it is an intended behavior. When you cancels query running if there was open transaction - it remains open until you explicitly commit or roll it back **OR** until connection is not closed

There is no any valuable mistakes in your pattern. If you control execution flow manually (Cancel Executing Query), then you should care of opened transactions in the same manner - manually.

**Update:**

The behavior is controlled by SSMS option *Disconnect after the query executes* - which means that the query disconnects after execution or cancel and rolls back opened transactions:
[image]

Comment: This answer seems to sidestep the spirit of the question... The question could be rephrased as "Why does cancelling a query not trigger the "catch" block of a try/catch construct?" If this is intended behaviour, why? As a designer of that proc, I expect the proc to either complete successfully or rollback - the implied semantics of try/catch do not allow for "stop executing but don't worry about the catch block, and leave the transaction open until SQL server decides to clean up the trasaction upon disconnection"... A sane behaviour would be to raise a "cancellation error", surely?

Comment: @Tao Maybe you're right, but the author accepted the answer, please, don't think for him.

Comment: Heh, I'll leave it with *no reference provided for the statement "Yes, it is an intended behavior"* then :)

Comment: @Tao Agree 8-) I'll place IMHO there

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question- Yes. This is expected behaviour.

*Wouldn't it just be easier to remember that a rollback is needed when manually cancelling the query?*

**Solution: Execute a rollback after manually cancelling any queries that begin transactions.**