# Does stopping query with a rollback guarantee a rollback

Tags: sql, sql-server

Say I have a query like this:

```
BEGIN Transaction
UPDATE Person SET Field=1
Rollback
```

There are one hundred million people.  I stopped the query after twenty minutes.  Will SQL Server rollback the records updated?

Comment: if you stopped the query then nothing will be committed because all the changes will be roll-back automatically.

Answer (score 11):

A single update will not update some rows. It will either update all or 0.

So, if you cancel the query, nothing will be updated.

This is [atomicity database systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_%28database_systems%29) which SQL Server follows.

In other words, you don't have to do that rollback at the end, nothing was committed anyway.

When you cancel a query, it will still hold locks until everything is rolled back so no need to panic.

You could test it yourself, execute the long query, cancel it and you will notice that it takes a while before the process really end.

Answer (score 2):

While the `update` statement will not complete, the transaction will still be open, so make sure you rollback manually or close out the window to kill the transaction. You can test this by including two statements in your transaction, where the first one finishes and you cancel while it's running the second - you can still commit the transaction after stopping it, and then get the first half of your results.

```
BEGIN Transaction
    UPDATE Person SET Field=1 WHERE Id = 1
    UPDATE Person SET Field=1
Rollback
```

If you start this, give it enough time for the first line to finish, hit the Stop button in SSMS, then execute `commit transaction`, you'll see that the first change did get applied. Since you obviously don't want part of a transaction to succeed, I'd just kill the whole window after you've stopped it so you can be sure everything's rolled back.

Comment: sql-server will hold locks and process untill it has rollbacked everything when you cancel, there is no need of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have opened the Transaction, Stoping the Query manually does not completes the transaction, This transaction will still be open and all the subsequent requests to this table will be blocked.

You can do any one of following options

1. Kill the Connection using the command KILL SPID (SPID is the process ID of your connection)
      Note: This will auto rollback the changes you made, you can monitor the rollback status with command  KILL SPID WITH STATUSONLY (After killing)
2. run the ROLLBACK command manually

** SPID is your request id, you can find it from sys.sysprocesses table/ you can also find it on Management Studio query Window the number which is within brackets / also you can find it at bottom right corner of your management studio beside the login name.

Example SQLQuery2.sql... (161) -- 161 is your spid.

Comment: This is a really important answer, I got burned hard by this today. Even selects against a table inside an unclosed transaction can cause DB performance hits depending on the transaction isolation level. According to this answer there is a setting in SSMS (if that's what you are using) that closes transactions after cancel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709058/transaction-is-still-open-after-cancelling-query